# Is it possible to use LED lamps in ceiling r80 eyeball fittings

Tags: lighting, led

I have a pair of eyeball style R80 100w fittings in my kitchen. These are horribly inefficient, so I recently tried replacing one of the bulbs with an 18w LED lamp (a LEDLite branded one from TLC direct) The light output was great, but the lamp lasted 4 days before it spluttered and died.

Inspection of the failed lamp revealed it was very hot, I therefore assume it overheated and that is what killed it.

Is it just not possible for an LED lamp to work in this kind of fitting, or is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

18 Watts is a lot for LED, so not surprising for it to be warm.

Sometimes LEDs have a slightly larger diameter and this may not allow them to screw in 100%, but this doesn't seem to be the case for you.

One suggestion is to take a flash light and examine the socket of the fixture for any evidence of arching.  Look for black or burnt streaks. The slightest damage to the socket could cause new bulbs to fail unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks! I've had a look at the socket and it has seen better days, might need to consider replacing it I think.

Comment: So in theory do you reckon I should be able to run LED lamps in this kind of fitting without overheating problems? Perhaps a slightly lower wattage, I've seen some 12w ones which claim 800+ lumens, almost as much as the 950 from the 18w which died.

Comment: I would consider buying your LEDs locally so if they go bad you can return them without much trouble.  Save the recipients.  The 240 Volt LED should be fine.  Have a look here http://catalog.gelighting.com/lamp/d=0/?r=emea

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is replace the trim with a R80 LED trim kit that has a LED lamp built-in.